# .NET Core: why is the result of ConfigurationBuilder["Key"] null when.ConfigurationBuilder.GertChildren has elements?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, environment-variables, registry

I have created a windows service using .NET Core 2.1 and added a set of environment variables:

```
Application_key1 = Key1
Application_key2 = Key2
Application_key3 = Key3
Application_key4 = Key4
Application_key5 = Key5
```

I am accessing it through:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables("Application_").Build();

return new ApplicationSettings
            {
                Key = configuration["key1"],
                //Get the rest of the keys
            };
```

Works great when I debug using my IDE. The environment variables get pulled out of my user settings just fine. When I run, the service, it doesn't pull the data reporting back a null reference exception. I then added the environment variables to the registry in HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/services/{Service} as a REG_MULTI_SZ:

[image: Registry Key]

I verified that the environment variables are correctly being pulled from the registry:

```
if (configuration == null)
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("Configuration is null", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var child in configuration.GetChildren())
                {
                    eventLog.WriteEntry($"Key: {child.Key} Value: {child.Value}", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                }
            }
```

It displays correctly in the event viewer. However, when I try to access the data:

`var a = configuration["key1"]`

the result is null. I don't really have a clue where to go next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the spaces between the equals signs for the environment variables to the registry:

```
Key1 = Value1
etc.
```

becomes

```
Key1=Value1
etc.
```